# xacro load yaml file with rospack

Tags: ros, yaml, rospack, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using xacro's new [ability to load a yaml file into a property](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#YAML_support) in order to update a URDF with new calibration data.

The file in the example is local. Is there any way to hook this up to rospack so I can include this xacro file in another one? I tried an inner $( ) but it didn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215443/xacro-load-yaml-file-with-rospack/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You apparently only need one set of `${}` per property. So rather than trying to double up with

```
<xacro:property name="filename" value="$(find package)/file.yaml"/>
<xacro:property name="dictionary" value="${load_yaml(${filename})}"/>
```

or

`<xacro:property name="dictionary" value="${load_yaml($(find package)/filename.yaml)}"/>`

like I tried to do, use two different properties, like so:

```
<xacro:property name="filename" value="$(find package)/file.yaml"/>
<xacro:property name="dictionary" value="${load_yaml(filename)}"/>
```

The filename will be substituted already since it's already in curly brackets. You don't need two sets.

Thanks to [Robert Haschke] for this answer.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2